# Apply function to every cell in DataFrame and include value from specific column

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a pandas DataFrame like so:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'add': [10, 20, 30]})
```

I would like to perform an operation on each cell in columns 'a' and 'b' that includes both the cell value and the value of the 'add' column for that row. Here's an example operation:

```
def add_vals(val, adder):
    if adder % val == 0:
        return val + adder
    else:
        return val + (val / adder)
```

I know I can do this with `df.apply`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to add the value in the `add` column to the function. My guess is the syntax is close to this, but I haven't gotten it to work:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(add_vals, args=(x['add'])))
```

What's the best way to do this in pandas? It doesn't have to be the most efficient, but I would like it to be good pandas code.

EDIT:

The output should look like this:

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'a': [11,22,33], 'b': [4.4,25,36]})
```

Comment: What output are you looking for?

Comment: @HenryEcker I have edited my question to include the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectorize `add_vals` method with `numpy.where`:

```
import numpy as np
def add_vals(vals, adders):
    return np.where(adders % vals == 0, vals + adders, vals + (vals / adders))
```

The method gives the transformation of a single column if you pass in `a` or `b` with the `add` column as 2nd parameter:

```
add_vals(df['a'], df['add'])
# [11. 22. 33.]
```

And then you can apply the method to each column (`a` and `b`) you want to transform:

```
df[['a', 'b']].apply(add_vals, adders=df['add'])

#      a     b
#0  11.0   4.4
#1  22.0  25.0
#2  33.0  36.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "add": [10, 20, 30]})
```

I then make a row function that apply your function to each row:

```
def add_vals(val, adder):
    if adder % val == 0:
        return val + adder
    else:
        return val + (val / adder)


def row_add_vals(df, col):
    return df.apply(lambda row: add_vals(row[col], row["add"]), axis=1)
```

Apply the function to each column:

```
df["a"] = row_add_vals(df, "a")
df["b"] = row_add_vals(df, "b")
```

Output:

```
    a     b  add
0  11   4.4   10
1  22  25.0   20
2  33  36.0   30
```